# Trouble reading single words without whitespace in C

Tags: c, printf

I'm working on a C program that involves reading only single words from the user input without including any whitespace. Here's a sample of my code:

```
 void handleMenu(char input[7]) {
    
        for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
            input[i] = toupper((unsigned char)input[i]);
        }
    
        if (strcmp(input, "LOAD") == 0) {
            load();
        } else if (strcmp(input, "CLEAR") == 0) {
            clear();
        } else if (strcmp(input, "LIST") == 0) {
            list();
        } else if (strcmp(input, "FOUNDP") == 0) {
            foundp();
        } else if (strcmp(input, "QUIT") == 0) {
            quit();
        } else {
            printf("\nInvalid option. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }

    int main() {
        char input[7];
    
        do {
            printf("\n%s\n", "------ Command Menu ------");
            printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "LOAD");
            printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "CLEAR");
            printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "LIST");
            printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "FOUNDP");
            printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "QUIT");
            printf("--------------------------\n");
            printf("\nChoose an option: ");
            scanf("%s", input);
            getchar();
    
            handleMenu(input);
    
        } while (strcmp(input, "QUIT") != 0);
    
        return 0;
    }
```

When the program asks "Choose an option:"
and i, for example, write "sdjbsfj".
The program responds with "Invalid option. Please try again."
which is good.

But then if i write "231 ajf 124"
The program will respond with "Invalid option. Please try again." 3 times, if i write 4 words it says the error warning 4 times, and so on.

What's wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide an reproducible sample of code, so that means: not including functions you do not provide into your code, writing your includes, etc.

Comment: Using `char input[7];` is asking for trouble. You have no protection against overflow, and it is highly likely that a user will type the wrong thing. Even `"sdjbsfj"` breaks the buffer. There is *undefined behaviour*. One solution is to define `char input[1000];` , read with `fgets()`, and remove the trailing newline.

Comment: `scanf("%s", input);` stops reading at the first whitespace, leaving the rest in the buffer. So `"231 ajf 124"` provides *three* inputs.

Comment: Also don't use a `getchar()` kludge after `scanf()` but understand how `scanf` handles whitespace (which isn't consistent across the different format specifiers). If you are going to use `scanf` then you need to spend at least an hour focussed entirely on that function, exploring its ins and outs.

Comment: Two general rules about `scanf` that you should always follow (assuming you disregard the more common rule "don't use scanf for anything, ever"): *always* check the return value, and *never* use `%s` without a width specifier.  eg, instead of `scanf("%s", input);` you should be writing `if (scanf("%6s", input) == 1) ....`  (Actually, you should structure your loop as `while (scanf("%6s", input) != EOF)` and include a break on `strcmp`)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you misunderstand the usage of `scanf`. This function considers a string to be any contiguous collection of non-whitespace characters, ignores preceding whitespace, and *stops reading at whitespace*. So you can get three reads from one line with three words. Instead of scanning for a string, I would use something like `fgets`, which allows you to accept a full line, and then I would process that.

For example

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

#define LINE_BUF 100
void handleMenu(char input[LINE_BUF]) {

    for (int i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
        input[i] = toupper((unsigned char)input[i]);
    }

    if (strcmp(input, "LOAD") == 0) {
        printf("\nLOAD introduced\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nError\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char input[LINE_BUF];

    do {
        printf("\n%s\n", "------ Command Menu ------");
        printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "LOAD");
        printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "CLEAR");
        printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "LIST");
        printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "FOUNDP");
        printf("%-10s %s\n", " ", "QUIT");
        printf("--------------------------\n");
        printf("\nChoose an option: ");
        
        if(fgets(input,LINE_BUF, stdin) == NULL) break;
        input[strcspn(input, "\n")] = 0;
        // the line above does the same as this one        
        // for (int i = 0; input[i]; ++i) if (input[i] == '\n') { input[i] = '\0'; break;}
        
        handleMenu(input);
    } while (strcmp(input, "QUIT") != 0 && strcmp(input, "quit") != 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

`fgets` is also safer, as you can indicate the buffer size, and you won't write over the end.

Update: Thanks to @chux-ReinstateMonica for comments below. Here's an updated working code snippet.

Comment: Rather than `strncmp(input, "LOAD", 4)`, consider lopping of the input's `'\n'` and use `strcmp(input, "LOAD")`.

Comment: When `fgets(input,LINE_BUF, stdin) != NULL` is false, `do { ... } while (strncmp(input, "QUIT", 4) != 0 && strncmp(input, "quit", 4) != 0 );` is likely an infinite loop.  Consider `if(fgets(input,LINE_BUF, stdin) == NULL) break;`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the tips! I'm also fairly new to C... Could you tell me why changing `\n` to `\0` is a better thing? Also, the infinite loop, I thought, was what the OP intended. That is, he'd like to repeatedly ask for the input until 'quit'.

Comment: "why changing \n to \0 is a better thing?" --> As is, input "LOADABC" matches `"LOAD"`.  I would expect `"Error"`.

Comment: When `fgets(input,LINE_BUF, stdin) == NULL`, then `stdin` has no more input and the loop will repeat - forever.  No `"quit"` will occur.

Comment: You're right. I just piped an empty file... I'll update the answer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359